# Multiple foreign keys to the same id. Django. Design Patterns

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I really can't figure out why I can't point by Foregin Key the exactly same id multiple times.

I'm trying to use Django ORM to the database that already exists. 
And it looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to create model according to that:

```
 class TestID(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    test_case_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    module = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    full_description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "TestID"

class TestCaseRun(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    soft_version = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    automated_test_case_version = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    checksum = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_case_id = models.ForeignKey(TestID, db_column='test_case_id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "TestCaseRun"

class TestStep(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCaseRun, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "TestStep"



class single_check(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    comparison = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)
    expected = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    actual = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    test_step_id = models.ForeignKey(TestStep, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "single_check"

class action(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    test_step_id = models.ForeignKey(TestStep, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "action"

class logs(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False)
    result = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    event_time = models.DateTimeField()
    test_step_id = models.ForeignKey(TestStep, db_column='id')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "logs"
```

When I try to run that code I get errors:

```
ERRORS:
web_report.TestStep: (models.E007) Field 'test_case' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
web_report.action: (models.E007) Field 'test_step_id' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
web_report.logs: (models.E007) Field 'test_step_id' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
web_report.single_check: (models.E007) Field 'test_step_id' has column name 'id' that is used by another field.
    HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.
```

And I really can not figure out why I can't point by Foregin Key the exactly same id multiple times. Imho nothing is wrong with this design. But I'm beginner in relational database design.

Comment: HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field...

Comment: This has nothing to do with using foreign key multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-column) argument incorrectly. This is the field on the model that you are linking from, not the column on the model that you are linking to. You cannot use `db_column='id'`, because there is already a primary key `id` for each model.

Taking your `TestStep` model as an example:

```
class TestStep(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCaseRun, db_column='id')
```

Your diagram shows that it is the `test_case_id` column that links to the `TestCase` model. So you should have:

```
    test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCaseRun, db_column='test_case_id')
```

or because that is the default, simply

```
    test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestCaseRun)
```

Comment: using db_column was also an error. I should use 'to_field'. `test_case = models.ForeignKey(TestID, to_field='test_case_id')`

Comment: Glad you got it working, but that's not what your diagram shows - it shows `test_case` linking to the `TestRun` model.